# The optimal way of MCU power consumption measurement

Tags: current

I'm trying to measure the power consumption of various MCUs(AVRs and STM32). For this measurement, a power supply and oscilloscope will be used. Because I want to plot the power usage vs time just like the following link, it is not possible to use multimeter and pwoermeter. They have bad time resolution and also delay. Thus power supply, oscilloscope and some ammeter will be used.

But in order to get nice accuracy, time resolution, I'd like to ask what kind of way is the best.

First, shunt ammeter seems not to be recommended, because the expected current draw on MCU would be 0~200mA. The way would show large error.

But I don't know which one is better between feedback ammeter and current probe. For time resolution I need 1~10ms and the currents will be in range of 0~100mA. But I have no idea which one would be better.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a linear regulator and have the ammeter measure the input of the regulator.  That way the unit under test still sees a constant voltage.  Make sure to put a ceramic cap immediately between the regulator input and its ground.

Comment: I'm sorry for not giving enough information. I would use a power supply, so it's expected that voltage would be constant. Also I'd prefer oscilloscope rather than multimeter or power meter, since they have bad time resolution and delay.

Comment: @sd11: That doesn't change anything I said.  You would still use your existing power supply as the input to a linear regulator, then put the ammeter or sense resistor between the two.  If you want a ground-referenced current signal, you can use a diff amp or a high side current sense chip, like the INA139, for example.  Or connect the scope probes to both ends of the sense resistor and put the scope in diffrence mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to measure the current in the time domain to see who the current varies as the code executes the current probe and oscilloscope is the most straightforward way. Although your accuracy may be limited.

Another way if you do not have a current probe is to use  allow value resistor as a shunt then amplify the voltage to a level suitable for a scope.  If you use for example a .1 ohm resistor the voltage drop will only be 10mV at your 100mA current consumption, this will not give a significant error in your consumption.  A single low offset voltage opamp can amplify this by 100 times to give a signal suitable of display on a scope.

If you just wish to measure the average current a normal ammeter need not result in a large error.

One way I have performed this test when measuring the current of a processor that has periods of drawing current then relatively long periods of no current is to put a large capacitor (several thousand microfarads) across the meter.  That will slow the meter response so it gives an average reading (what is needed to estimate battery life).  Also if you measure the voltage across the current meter in this situation you can compensate for the voltage drop by increasing the power supply voltage during the testing.

The voltage drop across a typical DVM when measuring current will be 200-500mV at full scale.